# How to use Java Regex to remove headers in text?

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a project where I read in a large amount of documents that all have similar headers. The headers start and end with the same words, but the words in between the start and end can vary. I am trying to use Pattern and Matcher to find these, but am having trouble. Here's my code:

```
Pattern docHeader = Pattern.compile("HEADER[ ]*:[.\\n\\t ]*header end");
```

So the header looks roughly like this:

```
HEADER:

random junk

random junk

header end

Document information start.
```

I am trying to delete all of the headers before I start scrubbing the text to save time on the back end. But it doesn't find my pattern ever. Suggestions?

Comment: use a buffered input stream, read line by line, once you get to **Document information start** do the actual job, ignoring everything before. Using RegEx is not much different than this. If the regex is a non-deterministic, the manual way is much better.

Comment: The document information start is just a place holder for my example. It is different every document.

Comment: Can you do the same thing that @HussainAl-Mutawa suggested, except replace "Document information start" with "header end"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Pattern for a RegEx solution:

```
Pattern docHeader = Pattern.compile("HEADER.*header end",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line without having to sully yourself with using `Pattern` etc:

```
String headlessInput = input.replaceAll("(?s)HEADER.*header end", "");
```

fyi, The regex expression `(?s)` turns on "dot matches newline" for the remainder of the regular expression.